# Phonegap + Android - Error when linking to local HTML

Tags: android, html, cordova

I have been trying to link to a local HTML file from my Phonegap app but it is not working. This is what I have in my index.html (which works perfectly)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>PhoneGap</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>  

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
     function onLoad(){
          document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
     }
     function onDeviceReady(){
          navigator.notification.alert("PhoneGap is working");
     }
  </script>

  </head>

  <body onload="onLoad();">
       <h1><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a></h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

page2.html is stored in the same assets/www folder as the index.html, it works on my desktop browser but nothing happens when I click the link on my device, except for an error which appears in the Log.

```
09-23 16:12:33.314: INFO/System.out(6244): startActivityForResult(intent,-1)

09-23 16:12:33.314: INFO/System.out(6244): Error loading url into DroidGap - file:///android_asset/www/page2.html:android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {ir.markdunne.hellophonegap/com.phonegap.DroidGap}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

If this was a standard android App the solution would be to create an activity tag for page2 in the manifest but I cannot do that here.

What is going wrong? Any help would be apprechiated

Comment: Why can't you edit your AndroidManifest? You should be able to, right? http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/30862722/phonegap-android-eclipse-quickstart#CreatingANewProject

Comment: I can, but there is nothing that I could add to help this problem

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a change in Phonegap 1.0.0. I solved it by adding the following to AndroidManifest.xml. Enter it as an additional activity block. Note that you need "intent-filter" as well. I tried the suggestion without "intent-filter" and it would not work.

```
<activity android:name="com.phonegap.DroidGap" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
<intent-filter>
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this activity into your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="com.phonegap.DroidGap"
                  android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
</activity>
```